# Remove/Adjust ghost image when dragging over specific element

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

From what I know there is a way to "hack" default behavior on `dragstart`. However is it possible somehow to only hide ghost image when dragging over specific area?

Desired result: I want let browser do the job until it gets over specific element - then I hide native drag image & provide custom one.
[image]

```js
let img = document.getElementById('img');
let div = document.getElementById('div');

div.addEventListener('dragenter', function() {
  div.style.background = 'yellow';
})

div.addEventListener('dragleave', function() {
  div.style.background = '';
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 40px
}
```

```html
<p>Drag'n'drop should use default ghost icon, unless drag over specific element</p>
<img id="img" draggable src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" />

<div id="div">Try dragging over me</div>
```

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage. For your exact use case it may be tricky, but it looks like you will need to create a second copy of the image as a hidden but "visible to the dom" element and use it as your drag image, then alter that dom element `ondragenter`

Comment: @SpencerMay from what I tried it "freezes" an image on `dragstart`, so that I can't adjust or hide it later on `ondragenter`

Comment: ``DataTransfer.setDragImage()`` can only be used at ``dragstart``. After that the drag image can not be manipulated. Even with an ID you can't apply any changes to it after ``dragstart``. So you will have to "build" your own drag image that you can manipulate on any event...

Comment: It says it stores a bitmap of the dragged image but it doesn't for an actual html element rather than an image element right?